# Access Linux Tomcat port 8080 from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat, firewall

My issue is that i cannot access (web-browse) my linux tomcat server from my windows local machine
So the Tomcat8 runs on RHL system on port 8080 and is configured in server.xml like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="localhost"
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxPostSize="262144"
maxThreads="250" minSpareThreads="25"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

The result if I try netstat command on application is this:

```
[root@XXXX]# sudo netstat -tanpu | grep ":8080"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21357/java
```

On my Windows 7 machine the netstat command return this:

```
netstat -na | find "10.111.XX.XXX"  
TCP    10.12X.XX.XXX:24093   10.11X.XX.XXX:22      ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.12X.XX.XXX:62502   10.11X.XX.XXX:22      ESTABLISHED
```

I don't know exactly where to search further for this issue, can someone maybe help?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the internal firewall blocks the 8080 port. Something like

```
iptables -nvL
```

will help

Comment: this is the result: iptables -L -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 7754 packets, 3742K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9577 packets, 2987K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: You can use simple telnet/putty/whatever to 8080 port of your linux host from your windows machine to check if you can connect there. Check your windows firewall rules as well to check if the network your linux clone is in is not 'public network' as it may block this port as well.

Comment: Run tcpdump on your linux machine to check if the incoming packets actually arrive to the host.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i cannot connect with putty on 8080 port and I see only incoming packets on 22 port

Comment: Have you run tcpdump on your linux host? Have you checked your windows firewall. You can run wireshark on your windows host and check if the packets are actually sent.

Comment: One more thing: if your linux host is a cloud one, check the allowed ports for it. Maybe they drop packets before they come to your host.

Comment: Actually running tcpdump -i eth0 port 8080 on linux shows me incoming packages from my windows machine when I try to access it. This tomcat server connects to a different linux host where is installed oracle restfull servicon top of Oracle DB and tries to get some data out there, those two hosts are in same network so there should be no issues there ... except maybe if something is not well configured

Comment: But i assume first i should see that the tomcat server is accessible on port 8080 ... now it returns 404